# How to obtain IP addresses of remote computers for initiating a call between two users located at different places?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am trying to develop a video calling application which could be executed on different web browsers, using webRTC. I have got stuck to a place where I am able to switch on my local machine camera, but I want to know how could I get the streaming of a person whom I want to call i.e. their video and how to get their IP address dynamically.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a signaling server where the clients can exchange their offer/answer messages.

The link Jonas w provided is a good place to start:
html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics

There is a sample app at:
https://appr.tc/

Source of sample app:
https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc